# Can't fetch arduino param on server, Using POST method via arduino wifi shield

Tags: shields

I am creating a slot sensor, using photoresistor.
The goal is to send the photoresistor value, via analog read, pin A0 to my web server, so I can stored it in my database.

`void loop() {
  int sensorvalue = analogRead(A0);// LightValue, read from sensor pin A0
  data = "sensorValue=" + (sensorvalue);
  //there is a car parked
  if(sensorvalue >=1000){
    if(flagstatus == false){
            if (client.connect(server, 80)){
              Serial.println("Connected to Host Server");
              client.println("POST /dataPost.php/HTTP/1.1"); 
              client.print("Host:");
              client.println(server); 
              client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              client.print("Content-Length: "); 
              client.println(data.length());
              client.println();
              client.print(data);`

I've been trying to send mock data via postman, and it works like a charm, so I can eliminate my server side from the equation. Been guessing using `:` or `=` on `sensorvalue=analogread(a0)` or `sensorvalue:analogread(a0)`. Or I made mistake on the code? I don't know much in Arduino, and this issue kinda frustrate me.

[image: arduinosetup]

the Image just for confirmation only, of course I installed the protoboard correctly.

`Connect to SSID: Adamar
IP Address: 192.168.1.14
Connect to server...
Connected with network---------
Connected to Host Server
sensorvalue:1007
There is still a car parked
sensorvalue:1007
There is still a car parked
sensorvalue:1008`

I manage to get this result from my serial monitor, so I think there is no wrong reading from my setup.

Comment: Before you start writing software that generates HTTP requests, you *really* should learn the format of an HTTP request.

Comment: hi, thank you for your friendly reminder :) Any suggestion? been go back and forth around this topic without any clear answer. About format, all snippets code, and example code from arduino written that way :)

Comment: You might want to look at the line "POST /dataPost.php/HTTP/1.1"

Comment: thank you for the hint on ``POST /dataPost.php/HTTP/1.1`` , could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: The correct format is `POST /dataPost.php HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Hi, thank you for spotting my mistake. I already update my arduino sketch. It almost took my breathe away, but I hate to say this. The issue persist.

``client.connect("the******tem.com", 80)){
      client.println("POST /dataPost.php HTTP/1.1"); 
      client.println("Host: the******tem.com");
      client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      client.print("Content-Length: "); 
      client.println(data.length());
      client.println();
      client.print(data);
      client.stop();``

already double check with http request format. Any idea about this?

Comment: you have not said anything about any errors that you are or are not getting

Comment: @jsotola Hi, thank you for highlight this. But I am really sorry, I didn't get any errors report.

Comment: print the response

Comment: hi @Juraj it is nice to meet you here. I read a lot your answers. You are such a big help for community.  What kind of response do you need? 

It confuse me, since we still can see sensor value from serial monitor. 

I would like to update this issue, it may be because of server hosting fault. I can manage to store data via ``GET`` although I understand it is not the best practice.

Comment: Thank you @Majenko :)